# Survey v petition

Tags: civipetiton, civisurvey

Looking back through SE, forums and docs, I am not seeing a lot of difference between using surveys v. petitions. My use case is conducting surveys for logged in members.

In the docs it says, https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/survey/what-you-need-to-know/#key-questions

> How many questions do you need to ask? If it is more than one, you
>   will need to create custom fields; if it is more than three, consider
>   using Petition instead of Survey.

Why is this? Surveys require multiple questions so I am curious as to why this says this in the docs.

Seems like an issue in terminology: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php%3Ftopic=23253.0.html

Using WP, so other than creating the custom fields and applying to an activity type, is there a reason to use Civi for the form or just go with Caldera Forms?

Comment: My experience is more with drupal, but yes we usually just use a custom Activity Type and do it via Webform, so assume the same can be achieved via Caldera. If you want the data stored in civi, then add custom fields to the Activity Type. If you just want to record who submitted the form, then you can just have the fields in Caldera only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a reason to use Civi for the form?

No.

Caldera form + activity processor allows you to do the same, with much more flexibility on how your form looks